# Jquery change fancybox attribute for an opened fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox v2.0.6.

I load an image inside the fancybox iframe as:

```
<a data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="imagefancybox" rel='gallery-image[ilist]' id={{image.id }} href="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}">
```

The imagefancybox class opens the fancybox as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".imagefancybox").fancybox({
         'scrolling'    : 'no',
         aspectRatio    : false,
         height         : '65%',
         width          : '90%',
         maxWidth       : 1200,
         minHeight      : 600,
         maxHeight      : 680,
         padding        : 0,
         margin         : 0,
         arrows         : true,
         nextEffect     : 'fade',
         prevEffect     : 'none',

    });
```

The image opens up in the fancybox correctly, and displays the previous and next navigation arrows as I have set arrows as true. This allows me to navigate to previous or next image by clicking on the image. I am trying to implement a tagging functionality so that when a user clicks on the image, the user can tag the image.  For this, when a user clicks a button in the image called 'Tag Image', I want to set 'arrows' as false in the already opened fancybox. How can I do this using jquery? 
});

Comment: did you try calling `$(".imagefancybox").fancybox({arrows: false})`?

Comment: I tried the above, and Firebug is giving me the following error in the console:

TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function

Comment: One option is to simple remove them with: $(".imagefancybox").find('#fancybox-left').remove(); and for the right one aswell.